# Using c++ static class member to control "mode" of all class instances

Tags: c++, class, constructor, static-members

This is a simple problem, but I would like suggestions on how to solve it.  I have a `Policy` class with constructor `Policy::Policy(const int& mode)`.

Depending on the value of `mode`, the `Policy` object can have different behavior and characteristics.  For example, let's say there are 3 possible modes of running my program corresponding to `mode=1`, `mode=2`, and `mode=3`.  Now, at no time would there ever be `Policy` objects with different mode values.

So, it makes sense to me that there would be a variable `static int Policy::MODE` so that all `Policy` objects know what mode they should be running under.  The very first `Policy` object created would set in its constructor the value of this static class variable.  Then, if any other `Policy` objects are attempted to be created with a **different** value of `mode`, the instantiation would exit with an error (because this should not ever be happening).

Any suggestions on how to solve this problem?

**[Additional explanation added below in response to comment request.]**

The program is for optimizing disease-screening policies.  Each `Policy` object represents a screening policy and has a lot of features necessary in order to keep track of statistics that reflect the impact of practicing that policy in a population.  In the parlance of optimization, each screening policy is a vector of decision variables and the objective function is estimated by simulating the policy using a natural history model of the disease.

The `Policy` object needs to be able to seamlessly fit within multiple complicated optimization frameworks.  It needs to be able to represent not only disease-screening policies, but also any number of standard test problems that can be used to test whether the optimization algorithms are working well.  The features/characteristics that change based on the `MODE` value of the `Policy` class are the following: (1) the simulation model used to evaluate the policy, (2) the code in the constructor that sets up things such as the length of the decision variables vector, and (3) the code used to display information about a given policy and its estimated performance.

For any particular simulation model (i.e. objective function), there are multiple "policy expressions" (i.e. vectors of decision variables) which can be decoded to the policy expression required by the simulation model.  So, each "mode" represents a pairing of a way of expressing a screening policy with a particular simulation model to evaluate that policy.

Leaving out a lot of non-relevant things, here would be the structure of the class if there were just 2 different modes of running:

```
class Policy {
public:

    vector<double> x; // encoded representation of a policy (decision variables)

    explicit Policy(const int& mode) {

        // set Policy::MODE if not already set (code not shown)

        switch(MODE) {
        case 1:
            // code...
            break;
        case 2:
            // code...
            break;
        }
    }

    void simulate() {

        switch(MODE) {
        case 1:
            // code...
            break;
        case 2:
            // code...
            break;
        }
    }

    void displayInfo() {

        switch(MODE) {
        case 1:
            // code...
            break;
        case 2:
            // code...
            break;
        }
    }

private:
    static int MODE;
};
```

At a high level, you could say that each mode value represents the pairing of a solution with an estimator.

Comment: The design sounds wrong. Each class should represent one thing, where `Policy` here represents 3. Can you elaborate a bit as to why you are doing it like this?

Comment: seems like it should be `explicit Policy::Policy(const int& mode)`

Comment: @AlexChamberlain I added an explanation of what I'm doing. Tell me if you have a better design suggestion.  Thanks!

Comment: Yeah, I have a much better suggestion; I'll write it up tomorrow, but in essence, this is what polymorphism is all about. Have a class for each mode that is a derivative of policy and implements its methods. You can have a static factory class which produces appropriate policies if you like.

Comment: @AlexChamberlain Great, thanks a lot.  I look forward to your write up.  I have never messed around with inheritance before.

Here's the only catch, possibly... Everywhere in my code where a Policy object is created, I would have to have conditional statements to create instances from different derived classes based on the "mode" of the problem.  So, it would mean that all the conditional statements get moved from the Policy class to other places in my code.  Know what I mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you asking for something like that:

```
static int Policy::MODE=-1;
Policy::Policy(const int& mode) {
  if (MODE==-1) {
    MODE=mode;
  }
  else {
    if (mode!=MODE) {
      cout <<"mode mismatch "<<...<<endl;
      exit (1); // or throw something, set some flags, depending on your needs
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Yes, exactly.  That's precisely what I had thought about.  I'm happy to see that others find this a good approach as well.